# Dynamic DataTable, Columns , Colomn 'Spans problem' [richfaces]

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I'm a new developer in jsf1.2 & richfaces 3.3.3, i have a problem with my jsf page, when viewing a dynamic dataTable, i can't build the head with a group column, knowing that i use columns in ColumnGroup, column Span and Row have no effect even if i give values or not!

the code for the head part of the table:

```
<rich:dataTable cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="700" border="0">

<f:facet name="header">
<rich:columnGroup>
<rich:columns  var="column" value="#{xmlBean.tableModele.head.column}">
    <rich:column breakBefore="#column.breakBefore}"  rowspan="#{column.rowSpan}" colspan="#{column.colSpan}">
          <h:outputText value="#{column.libelle}" rendered="#{column.champ.type=='text'}" />

</rich:column>
</rich:columns>
</rich:columnGroup>
</f:facet>

</rich:dataTable>
```

Comment: hey could u please explain where is this value from 
xmlBean.tableModele.head.column

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem :), it was necessary that i remove the "column" without 's', because the "columns" generate "column")

the code  :

```
<f:facet name="header">
  <rich:columnGroup>

      <rich:columns var="column" value="#{xmlBean.tableModele.head.column}" rowspan="#{column.rowSpan}" colspan="#{column.colSpan}" breakBefore="#{column.breakBefore}">
                                <h:outputText value="#{column.champ.valeur}" rendered="#{column.champ.type=='text'}" />
       </rich:columns>

   </rich:columnGroup>

</f:facet>
```

thanks, its my fist post, i'm glad to be here ;)